# Asp.Net Dynamic Data + Complex Types

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

Is there any way how to work with complex types in asp.net dynamic data web site?

If we have Entity(ie from EF) "Person" with complex type "Address",  "Table.GetScaffoldColumns()" does not returns comlumns for property of type "Address".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Running into this issue as well.   Complex types in my model do not show up in the Dynamic Data Site.

Comment: hmmm - doesn't look good for getting this out of the box....

http://forums.asp.net/t/1534620.aspx

Has anyone tackled this?

Comment: Reading the comments on that link a little more, it sounds like you can access the Complex types by implementing your own custom pages and using BoundFields or TemplateFields instead of the DynamicFields and DynamicControls...  defeats the purpose a bit if you have to end up coding that up by hand.

Comment: Is there any update on this? It seems that it's still not possible with complex properties... :(